# How to get to your settings without a home screen app?

Tags: settings, launcherpro

I hadn't used my old HTC Hero for a while, but when I rebooted it I got an error saying:

`LauncherPro has expired, please download an updated version.`

But wifi was turned off and when I tried to get to the home screen, it kept sending me back into the browser. So how can I get to my settings, so I can turn on wifi to download it?

Or is there another way of updating it without me requiring to go to my settings?

Comment: This was a big to-do recently. Let me hunt down the instructions to get around it. (It's also why I uninstalled LauncherPro.)

Comment: I suppose getting to the Market website via 3G is out of the question?

Comment: You can't even turn on 3G either, so nope

Comment: I love LauncherPro, but the dev really shot himself in the foot over this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found this at: http://orlygoingthirty.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-uninstall-expired-launcherpro.html

> I finally found a workable solution:
>   download the latest LauncherPro APK
>   (or hopefully any other APK). Connect
>   your phone to your PC and mount the SD
>   card. Copy the new APK to the
>   top-level of the SD card and rename it
>   to something short (like lp.apk).
>
> Unmount the phone, then in the phone
>   browser (which is the only thing LP
>   lets you run), type the following in
>   the URL bar:
>
> file:///sdcard/lp.apk
>
> (notice the three slashes)
>
> This will force-launch the Installer
>   application on the phone. Now on my
>   phone, it was set to disallow
>   non-Android Market apps from
>   installing; since the APK is not off
>   the Android Market, the phone popped
>   up an error and offered to let me
>   change the application setting. Which
>   launches the Settings application.

Comment: I already had the new installer on the SD card, but didn't know how to find it. I guess I missed one of the three /'s in this link I found elsewhere: market://search?q=pnamerg.adw.launcher. Since that one didn't work.

Comment: Glad I could help. I recommend Zeam as a home screen alternative.

Comment: @al Yay Zeam!!1

Comment: Installed Zeam now, like how light it is :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, the developer looks like he is stepping away for a while.

Answer (score 3):

Really all that was really necessary was to click on the phone's search button and type in "settings".  The top result should be the "Settings" application.  You click on that and it opens your settings app so that you can got to Applications:Manage Applications where you can scroll down to LauncherPro click on it and then click on the "Clear defaults" button.  Now when you click on the home key it will bring up a list of any Launcher programs you have installed, including the factory installed one which you can now select.

Comment: I can't verify it anymore, sadly. Though might this not depend on what version of Google Search you have on your phone? Most of my search results just took me back to the browser, without even previewing other results as it does on my HTC Desire HD. If it works though, great suggestion!

Comment: Under Settings:Search:Searchable items Apps should be checked off as a default.  If this is the case, installed apps (i.e. "Settings") will be searched and listed.