# Default launcher broken, causing infinite loop of force closes

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, custom-roms, launcher, force-close

I've just installed a custom rom and restored my apps from Titanium. However, now the default Launcher app is broken and I can't get out of the infinite loop of force closing. I can't press menu or anything to remove it as default. How do I get out of this pickle?

I have a GT-i9000.

Comment: Also, try using [safe mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6458/how-would-you-uninstall-a-rogue-home-launcher-application/6470#6470). You haven't mentioned which device and version of Android you're using, so it's hard to help.

Comment: Are you using the stock TouchWiz launcher or another?

Comment: @MatthewRead I've had TouchWiz go into an infinite crash loop just from booting normally! Fortunately, a reboot fixed the problem, but still...

Answer (score 3):

Did you have web install working? Then you can try installing an alternative launcher through the [web-based Android Market](https://market.android.com/), and that will (hopefully) cause the default launcher to be reset.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem after upgrading from stock 2.3.3 to rooted JVR 2.3.4.  After the upgrade pretty much every app and background process constantly force closed - including launcherpro.

By pressing and holding the home button very quickly after I closed the FC messages I was eventually able to bring up the "recent apps" window, then select task manager, and from there I was able to uninstall LauncherPro.

However after a bit more mucking around I decided to do a factory reset, as pretty much every app on the phone was broken.

Before I did the upgrade I had backed up my call logs & sms messages, and used listables to generate a HTML file with all of my installed apps, and I used this list to install the apps I wanted to keep again.

Answer (score 0):

If this infinite loop is causing Android touch / mouse to be unresponsive, you should uninstall the faulty App with an external Keyboard:

Connect an **external USB keyboard** -> Then press **F3 key** to open Android Setting menu -> Uninstall in Application Manager.