# ADW Launcher crashing on home screen

Tags: crashes, adw.launcher, themes

I installed the wrong theme for ADW and now it crashes every time the home screen displays.

Since the home screen keeps crashing, I can't seem to reach the settings pannel to disable the stupid theme.

I've also tried "Safe Mode" but so far it doesn't help.

Comment: This should help (may even be a duplicate): http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4910/how-to-get-to-your-settings-without-a-home-screen-app

Comment: @Al Everett - That looks like it has to do with the issue that Launcher Pro had where it was saying it was expired. Launcher Pro automatically opened the browser which made it easy to download an update. If the launcher is crashing, there is no real way to open any application.

Answer (score 3):

Try installing another launcher. Then press the Home key and it will ask you which launcher to use. Select the "new one". Then try going in to Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications -> ADW and Clear the data.

You will probably also want to delete the "settings backups" that are stored on the sdcard, if you created them.

Then you should be able to switch back to ADW.

If you can't get to the market to install another launcher, you will probably have to side load i using ADB.

Or as Lie Ryan suggests, use the Market Web interface to install another launcher.

Comment: or try push installing from the web-based Android market.

Answer (score 0):

There's a much cleaner solution to this, which will work if you have email notifications in the status bar, and can turn internet access on from the status bar widgets. I found it in [this xda-developers thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1257203); many thanks to aps786 for getting me out of a fix.

> Problem already solved but just for others visiting this thread, there is a way to get rid of the issue (which worked for me). when there was crash in ADW Launcher, statusbar still works. This is to key to get back to original theme (as you can't access settings directly to set default theme)
>
> - Opened status bar, start internet.
> - From another device (or desktop machine), send a mail to yourself with google play link for the new theme you just installed
> - Your status bar will now have new mail notification (assume its activated)
> - Now access your mail app and open the link from the mail
> - Now you have browser app opened with google play page
> - You will have uninsatll option for that theme. Just do it.
> - Now as new theme is uninstalled, your default theme will come in picture and everything will be normal.
>
> I hope this will help others fall in similar situation after installing new theme.

I suspect you could also do this using SMS, WhatsApp, or any messaging application that can get to your notification bar.